# Iterate over integer in javascript where each value equals a single digit

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, integer, iteration

I would like to use the `$.each()` loop to iterate over digits in an integer.
The integer is produced as the index of another array, though I'm not sure that this makes a difference.

**Javascript**

```
var words = [ "This", "is", "an", "array", "of", "words","with", "a", "length", "greater", "than", "ten." ];
var numbers = [];
$.each(words, function(i,word) {
    $.each(i, function(index,value) {
        $(numbers).append(value);
    });
});
```

I would like the array `numbers` to equal the following array:

```
[ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 0, 1, 1 ]
```

Where the last four entries, `[ ... 1, 0, 1, 1 ]` are generated through iteration over the indexes for the entries `[ ... "than", "ten." ]` in the `words` array.

Comment: I dont understand your issue. You want to itterate over an Integer? How is this possible?

Comment: huh? How do you get 1, 0, 1, 1?

Comment: Are you saying that `than` is 10 and you get 1, 0 from making 10 = 1, 0 and 11 = 1, 1? You are changing the index to a string and iterating over that? Why?

Comment: Yes, basically. I want to convert the integers into string values, so 1 becomes "one", but, for what I wish to use it for, a plugin is overkill... so I just wanted to know the most efficient way to read integers as individual digits and this seemed the most logical, linear way to explain my desired result.

Comment: ... or maybe I've just been staring at code too long today and need a break...

Comment: 1 !== "1" !== "one" and most certainly 10 !== "10" !== [1,0] !== "ten". I have no idea what you are doing now.

Comment: If there are 100 words in the word array are the last three numbers in the number array [1, 0 ,0]?

Comment: I know what you are saying. So, in theory, I would need to work from binary? (If that is the case then obv. not worth the effort).

Well, the last two in the number array would be [...9, 9]... and 101 words would result in a numbers array ending with [... 1, 0, 0] because I am counting indexes which start from 0.

But yes, you are interpreting my logic correctly.

Do you know of some plugin or efficient way of doing this by converting to string? I have tried multiple approaches it just seemed that the example I gave within the question would be best to exemplify my desired input/output.

Comment: I forgot to mention, I have separately created a switch function which would convert the resulting integer values to strings (... case 0: return "zero"; etc.)... I just felt that the addition of this would reduce the clarity of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
let words = [ "This", "is", "an", "array", "of", "words","with", "a", "length", "greater", "than", "ten." ];

let numbers = words.map((w, i) => i.toString().split('').map(Number)) //map into array of digits
    numbers = Array.prototype.concat.call(...numbers); //concat them all
 console.log(numbers);
```